# Show Columns Total Value in tfooter using html table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in asp mvc and creating small application in mvc4. I have a problem I make index view which show list of all purchase contract which contain (cost, quantity,discount,tax) column.I want total value of all four column in tfooter how can I do this please help me.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your view is some thing like

```
@model List<Models.Purchase>

@{
    var totalCost=Model.sum(a=>a.Cost);
    var totalQty=Model.sum(a=>a.Qty);
    var totalDiscount=Model.sum(a=>a.Discount);
    var totalTax=Model.sum(a=>a.Tax);
}
<table>
  <tr><th>Cost</th><th>Qty</th><th>Discount</th><th>Tax</th></tr>
  @foreach(var item in Model)
  {
        <tr><td>@item.Cost</td><td>@item.Qty</td><td>@item.Discount</td><td>@item.Tax</td></tr>
  }
  <tr><th>@totalCost</th><th>@totalQty</th><th>@totalDiscount</th><th>@totalTax</th></tr>     
</table>
```

Please try this. I hope you can understand.